# Gtk-WARNING **: 20:45:08.481: Locale not supported by C library. Using the fallback 'C' locale

Tags: centos7, kvm-virtualization, xen

```
[root@server ~]# virt-manager

Gtk-WARNING **: 20:45:08.481: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
    (virt-manager:10415): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:45:08.482: cannot open display: 
    
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

The above output is the error. Please provide the solution.

OS - centos7
Using XEN Virtualization - KVM

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.

Comment: The problem is not the locale, the problem is `cannot open display`. Google it.

Comment: Or Easier said: you need a X-System to open virt-manager it requires a graphical interface not only the console.